# Mask JQuery funcionando apenas para um campo

Tags: jquery, html

Caros, em meu código preciso inserir duas `mask`, porém, apenas de `INSC_EST` está funcionando, a outra não.
Segue o código:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.7.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>

    $(function() {$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();});  
    $(function() {$( "#tabs" ).tabs();});
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("input.INSC_EST").mask("999.999.999-9999");
       $("input.CGC").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    });

   <fieldset id="Fiscal" class="Fiscal">
     <legend><b>Fiscal:</b></legend>
       <label for="Natureza">
            Natureza:   
         <select name="NATUREZA">
           <option value="1">Pessoa Fisica</option>
           <option value="2" selected>Pessoa Juridica</option>
           <option value="3">Trading</option>
         </select>
       </label>
       <label for="CGC">
         CGC:<input type="text" class="CGC" name="CGC" id="CGC" value="" />
       </label>
       <label for="INSC_MUNIC">
         Insc. Municipal:<input class="class5" type="text" name="INSC_MUNIC" MAXLENGTH="11" value=""/>
       </label>
         <label for="INSC_EST">
         Insc. Estadual:    <input class="INSC_EST" type="text" name="INSC_EST" value=""/>
       </label>
         <label for="ST">
           ST: <select>
           <option value="1" selected>SIM</option>
           <option value="2">NAO</option>
           </select>
         </label>

  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Removi minha resposta, acho que errei o Plugin que você esta usando...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código funciona, a prova está aqui:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryw18wax/1/

O que eu notei foi que as máscaras só são aplicadas quando você informa todos os números, o que provavelmente não é o que você quer.

Note que fiz uma pequena alteração aqui:

```
$("input.INSC_EST").mask("999.999.999-9999");
$("input.CGC").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
```

Acrescente o parametro **reverse** para que o componente formate o campo na medida que você informar os valores, desta forma:

```
$("input.INSC_EST").mask("999.999.999-9999", {reverse: true});
$("input.CGC").mask("99.999.999/9999-99", {reverse: true});
```

**EDIT**

Este componente é muito bem documentado, segue um show case com vários exemplos:

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, isso é exatamente o que quero. Eu vi que esta funcionando, mas infelizmente para mim nao esta funcionando, ainda estou com o mesmo caso e , mesmo inserindo o reverse, este tambem nao funciona, pois ao clicar no campo a mask ja é mostrada.

Comment: @Thiago Aparece alguma coisa no console? Porque você importa duas versões do jQuery?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, está tudo funcionando perfeitamente. O principal erro estava no script jQuery-Mask-Plugin.js. Baixei ele novamente e a mask funcionou prefeitamente, ainda melhor graças ao reverse:true.